# Python Pandas Vlookup

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to merge two excel files by using Vlookup function from excel in Python.

based on my code, the result would be:

```
col1_x | col2_x | col3_x | col4_y | col5_y | col6_y 
   1        2        3       4        5        6
   7        8        9       10       11       12
```

My code :

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("dropped_file.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("original.xlsx")

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['col1', 'col3', 'col4'], how='left')
result.to_excel("result.xlsx", index=False)
```

Anyone have idea to drop out _x and _y at behind of column names ?

Comment: So reason for `_x` and `_y` is after merge are duplicated columns names. So for avoid `col1, col1, col2, col2` ouput is added `_x, _y` so ouput is `col1_x, col1_y, col2_x, col2_y`

Comment: `result.columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6' ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason for `_x` and `_y` is after merge are duplicated columns names. So for avoid `col1`, `col1`, `col2`, `col2` columns is added `_x`, `_y` so ouput is `col1_x`, `col1_y`, `col2_x`, `col2_y`.

If need remove `_x, _y` but ouput will be duplicated columns use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_x|_y','', regex=True)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     1     2     3     4     5     6
1     7     8     9    10    11    12
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, Thanks for your answer and it really helped me a lot :)